# Not being able to call build_vk_surface() on a WindowBuild object

Tags: rust, vulkan, rust-cargo

I am following the vulkano tutorial to open a window and create a surface with `vulkano-win`.

Most of the tutorial is dated which I've been able to work around so far, however I have not been able to find a solution.

Currently, I get the following error when I call `let window = WindowBuilder::new().build_vk_surface(&events_loop, instance.clone())`

`error[E0599]: no method named build_vk_surface found for struct winit::window::WindowBuilder in the current scope`

I have checked the library and the version of `vulkano_win` and it seems to properly extend `WindowBuilder` I will post the dependencies in my `Cargo.toml` below.

```
[dependencies]
vulkano = "0.19"
vulkano-shaders = "0.18"
winit = "0.23"
vulkano-win = "0.19"
image = "0.23"
```

P.S. - There is a legacy instance of this happening on a much older (2 yr ago) version of `vulkano_win` here. I suspect this has been fixed since I have checked the dependencies for the `vulkano_win` library and they use the newer and restructured versions of `winit` there:
https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano/issues/943

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have checked the library and the version of `vulkano_win` and it seems to properly extend `WindowBuilder` I will post the dependencies in my `Cargo.toml` below.

In short, you are *correct*. The issue is that the `VkSurfaceBuild` trait, is implemented for winit 0.22's `WindowBuilder` and not winit 0.23's `WindowBuilder`.

So to fix your issue, you need to update your Cargo.toml to use winit 0.22 instead of 0.23.

Example:

```
[dependencies]
vulkano = "0.19"
vulkano-shaders = "0.19"
vulkano-win = "0.19"
winit = "0.22"
```

---

Additionally, your confusion might come from browsing the repository.
In the repository both [vulkano-win](https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano/blob/master/vulkano-win/Cargo.toml) and the [examples](https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano/blob/master/examples/Cargo.toml) uses winit 0.23.
However, remember that the current state of the repository is not necessarily the same as what was released in 0.19.

On GitHub you can select tags, and view the commit that *was* the [0.19 release](https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano/tree/v0.19.0).
If you then look at [vulkano-win](https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano/blob/v0.19.0/vulkano-win/Cargo.toml) and the [examples](https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano/blob/v0.19.0/examples/Cargo.toml), you'll see that they all use winit 0.22.

[image: repo]

If you really want to use winit 0.23. Then you could depend directly on the repository. Like this:

```
[dependencies]
vulkano = { git = "https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano" }
vulkano-win = { git = "https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano" }
vulkano-shaders = { git = "https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano" }
winit = "0.23"
```

However, one breaking change to the repository, could potentially ruin your build. So use with caution.

---

> How were able to determine how that trait was implemented over the 0.22 `WindowBuilder` but not the 0.23 `WindowBuilder`?

Unsure if there's a fancy way of doing it, but an easy way is to just go to [VkSurfaceBuild on docs.rs](https://docs.rs/vulkano-win/0.19.0/vulkano_win/trait.VkSurfaceBuild.html), then at "Implementations on Foreign Types" if you click on `WindowBuilder`, then it redirects to [winit 0.22.2 docs](https://docs.rs/winit/0.22.2/winit/window/struct.WindowBuilder.html).

Alternatively, you can also check your `Cargo.lock`. If you attempt to use `winit 0.23`, then your `Cargo.lock` would contain two `winit` versions:

```
[[package]]
name = "winit"
version = "0.22.2"
...

[[package]]
name = "winit"
version = "0.23.0"
...
```

If you then peek at `vulkano-win` then you can see it uses `winit 0.22.2`:

```
[[package]]
name = "vulkano-win"
version = "0.19.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "0b9a02addddf5532396d11dbb822f77d87ca17a00c918e4c8a0a125d6c207e2b"
dependencies = [
 "cocoa 0.20.2",
 "metal",
 "objc",
 "vulkano",
 "winit 0.22.2",
]
```

*If there's no duplicate versions, it would just say `"winit"` like the others.*

Comment: You're welcome! I updated the answer to elaborate a bit on how I go about figuring it out. But honestly, it's more a "rule of thumb". If a trait is implemented and included, but still gives that error, then it's probably some versions clashing.